# Can Inverse of a 'matrix over field' have all entries from some subfield

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

If $A$ is some $n\times n$ (pure)complex matrix and is invertible, then is it possible that $A^{-1}$ may have real entries?
This question popped up in my mind while reading some linear algebra and I think answer is NO but not sure how to prove it.
A more general question to ask is as follows :
If $\mathbb{F}_1$ is a (proper)subfield of $\mathbb{F}$ and $A$ is a invertible matrix having entries from $\mathbb{F}-\mathbb{F}_1$, then is it possible that $A^{-1}$ have all entries from $\mathbb{F}_1$?
Any hint will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: For the real case, it's easy to show. Asking if a non-real matrix can have a real inverse is equivalent to asking if a real matrix can have a non-real inverse. However, the inverse of  a matrix with real entries (when it exists) is also real, because the inverse is the adjugate of A (also real), divided by the determinant (also real). Maybe this proof generalizes?

Comment: @Believer: Elchanan's comment gives you the answer. If a matrix $B$ has entries in $\mathbb{F}_1$ and $\mathbb{F}_1 \subsetneq \mathbb{F}$ then $B$ is invertible as a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}_1$ iff it is invertible as a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}$ and all the entries of $B^{-1}$ belong to $\mathbb{F}_1$. The reason is that $B$ is invertible iff $\det(B) = 0$ and $\det(B)$ is the same, whether you calculate it in $\mathbb{F}_1$ or $\mathbb{F}$. Then the formula $B^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det{B}} \operatorname{adj}(B)$ shows that all the entries of $B^{-1}$ belong to $\mathbb{F}_1$

Comment: because $\det(B) \in \mathbb{F}_1$ and all the entries of $\operatorname{adj}(B)$ also belong to $\mathbb{F}_1$ (being up to a sign the determinants of submatrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_1$). In particular, if $B = A^{-1}$ has all entries in $\mathbb{F}_1$ then also $B^{-1} = \left( A^{-1} \right)^{-1} = A$ must have all entries in $\mathbb{F}_1$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is a field and $A\in F^{n\times n}$, then $A^{-1}\in F^{n\times n}$. Therefore, if $A^{-1}\in F^{n\times n}$, then $A=(A^{-1})^{-1}\in F^{n\times n}$. This means that if all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are in some subfield $F_1$ then all the entries of $A$ are in $F_1$ as well. In short, the entries of $A$ and the entries of $A^{-1}$ generate the same field over the base field.

It's possible for a matrix $A$ with all entries in $\Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$ to have $A^{-1}$ with some real entry. For instance, $$\left(i\begin{pmatrix}1&2&1\\ 3&5&1\\x&y&z\end{pmatrix}\right)^{-1}=\frac1{(3x-2y+z)i}\begin{pmatrix}y-5z&2z-y&3\\ 3z-x&x-z&-2\\5x-3y&y-2x&1\end{pmatrix}$$

and you can force a zero entry with, say, $x=1$, $y=\frac53$ and $z=10000$.

I would assume that this can be done quite often, if not all the time.